# Rails routing: wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and now learning routing, here's what I have in my `routes.rb`:

```
match '/text' => 'text#index'
match '/text/:id' => 'text#show'
```

And here's my `app/views/text/index.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Texts</h1>
<% @texts.each do |t| %>
    <div><%= link_to t.title, text_path(t) %></div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when I click on the link, it redirects my to '/text.1' rather than '/text/1'. Can anyone figure out how why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like texts are a resource in your app - you should be using [resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

For this exact case, if for some reason you don't want to use resource routing, you should look at the output of your `rake routes` and see what name is being assigned to your `text#show` route and use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 


   <h1>Texts</h1>
    <% @texts.each do |t| %>
       <div><%= link_to t.title, t %></div>
     <% end %>
```

or this

```
   <h1>Texts</h1>
    <% @texts.each do |t| %>
       <div><%= link_to t.title, text_path(:id => t.id) %></div>
     <% end %>
```